# Método Remove(item) Não funciona Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho um método que usa o remove para retirar da lista. mas não da certo, não da erro, e nem remove.

primeiro eu vou no banco buscar o objeto.

```
 var ctrl = _controleDeVisitaRepositorio.BuscarPorIdIncluso(controle.ControleDeVisitasId);
```

depois eu crio uma nova lista, com os IDs, que vem como parametro:

```
List<TipoDeSistemas> ts = new List<TipoDeSistemas>();
                //adicionar os objetos Tipo de sistemas a lista
                foreach (var t in sistemasComerciais)
                {
                    //buscaca o sistema no banco
                    var tt = _tipoDeSistemaRepositorio.BuscarPorId(t ?? Guid.Empty);
                    //adiciona a lista
                    ts.Add(tt);
                }
```

mas o meu problema está aqui, ele entra no if, mas não remove o item que eu quero:

```
if (ts.Count() < lista2.Count())
                    {
                        var tsds = ts.Except(lista2).ToList();
                        foreach (var t in tsds)
                        {
                            ctrl.TipoDeSistemas.Remove(t);
                            db.Entry(ctrl).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }

                    }
```

Onde estou errando??

Comment: Você deve informar ao EF que você está removendo o `TipoDeSistemas` da lista.
Pode fazer um filtro percorrendo o objeto e depois "Setar" como `EntityState.Deleted`

Comment: O que sugeri resolveu?